# Number of orderings of subset sums

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, computational-complexity

**In short:** In how many ways can all $2^n$ subset sums of $n$ real numbers $a_1,\ldots, a_n$ be ordered? I am not concerned about the case in which different subsets sum to the same number; you may assume all $2^n$ subset sums are distinct.

**Example:** Suppose $n=2$. There are four subset sums: $0$, $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_1+a_2$. There are eight possible orderings:
\begin{eqnarray}
0 &<& a_1 < a_2 < a_1 + a_2\\
0 &<& a_2 < a_1 < a_1 + a_2\\
a_1 &<& 0 < a_1 + a_2 < a_2 \\
a_2 &<& 0 < a_1 + a_2 < a_1 \\
a_1 &<& a_1 + a_2 < 0 < a_2 \\
a_2 &<& a_1 + a_2 < 0 < a_1 \\
a_1 + a_2 &<& a_2 < a_1 < 0 \\
a_1 + a_2 &<& a_1 < a_2 < 0.
\end{eqnarray}
All other orderings of these four expressions, such as
$$
a_1 + a_2 < 0 < a_1 < a_2
$$
are not possible.

**Motivation:** This problem is directly related to the well-known NP-complete "subset sum" problem in computer science. I am wondering whether the pure combinatorics of that problem render it especially difficult.

My guess is that the problem I pose here has been asked before: I think it's a pretty straightforward way to understand something about the difficulty of the subset sum problem.

Comment: Attempt: Split the problem into the cases with given number of negative and positive $a_{i}$. Write down all ordered sequences which are prescribed by this conditions. Count all possible sequences which contain ordered sequences. Use permutation of the $a_{i}$'s which are interchangeable. The number of permutations of $n$ objects is $n!$. Find a formula for the number of that sequences.

Comment: Equivalently: Consider the $(3^n-1)/2$ hyperplanes passing through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose normal vectors have all coordinates in $\{-1,0,1\}$.  Into how many regions do they divide $\mathbb{R}^n$?  It seems like the answer may be $96$ for $n=3$ (just based on testing a $100\times100\times100$ grid of points and seeing what side of each plane they fall on).  This fits several OEIS sequences, but none that seem to mention this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive approach.

Let $n$ be the order of a set. So it has $2^n$ subsets. Define $f(n)$ as the number of possible orderings if the input is the order $n$ of a set.

I claim that $f(n+1)=f(n).[(2^n)(2^n-1)+2]$

Now, to give a weak proof, I would explain it this way: Let's assume we know all possible orderings for sets of order $n=k$. Let's focus on one of the possible orderings. Then, we mark the numbers, corresponding to each sum, on a axis of real number with spikes. To make an ordering of a set of order $n=k+1$, we add an arbitrary number to the marked numbers. So, actually we are shifting the numbers that we had. To imagine it more conveniently, we can make a duplicate of the axis (with the same spikes) that we had for $n=k$ and put it below the original one. Adding a new number to a set is equivalent to shift the duplicate axis with the amount of the new member.

The next step is to see how the new possibilities for $n=k+1$ is created. As we need to consider all possibilities, we may take a new member $x$ which is variable. $x$ starts from $0$ and goes to infinity and $x$ actually shifts the lower axis. Every time two spikes from the lower and the upper axes passes each other, we have a new ordering. The first spike, from the lower axis, would pass $2^k-1$ spikes, from the upper axis. The second spike would pass $2^k-2$ spikes and so on. Hence, we have a total of $(\sum_{i=1}^\mathbb{2^k-1} i)+1=(2^k-1)+(2^k-2)+...+1+1$ (the one at the end is an adjustment) possibilities for a positive $x$. If negative $x$ cases are counted, the final result would be $(2^k)(2^k-1)+2$. Note that this is for one ordering of order $n=k$. So we multiply it by the number of possible orderings of $n=k$ which is $f(k)$.

Comment: Nice idea! But I do not understand the details. Suppose we allow negative numbers. Then, each spike from the lower axis passes $2^k$ spikes from the upper axis, so the final result should be $f(k)\cdot (2^k)^2$.

Comment: No. you have considered all the spikes of the lower axis to be at the right of every spikes of the upper axis. They need to start from the same position.

Comment: @Mad but what if we allow $x$ to be negative? Then, $x$ starts at minus infinity and goes to infinity.

Comment: I think I should have made it more clear. For negative x, x goes from 0 to minus infinity. So, the lower axis moves in the opposite direction. It is a mirror case of positive x. hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure about this solution.  It seems like some of the spike passes must be simultaneous, reducing the number of orderings.  As a concrete example, suppose that we have $n=2$ and our initial ordering is $0<a_1<a_2<a_1+a_2$.  The positive values of $x$ where we have a spike pass occurring would then correspond to the positive differences of elements of $\{0, a_1, a_2, a_1+a_2\}$.  But there's only at most $4$ such differences, not $6$, because $(a_1+a_2)-a_1=a_2-0$ and $(a_1+a_2)-a_2=a_1-0$.  In spike terms, the $a_1$ spike passes the $a_1+a_2$ spike at the same time the $0$ passes $a_2$